# How could Tisamon catch Tynisa's blade one handed this way?

Tags: shadows-of-the-apt

I've been listening to [Empire of Black and Gold, Shadows of the Apt](https://www.panmacmillan.com/authors/adrian-tchaikovsky/empire-in-black-and-gold/9781529050264).

When Tisamon sees Tynisa and the draw blades on each other. He catches her rapier "*between his palm and the spines of his forearm*".

> There was the hilt of her sword and the narrow blade . . . and
> Tisamon’s hand was flat against it, and the rapier’s length caught
> between his palm and the spines of his forearm. Its point was frozen
> over Stenwold’s shoulder, trapped on its way directly towards
> Tisamon’s face. Tisamon’s other arm, his right, was across Stenwold’s
> shoulders, the spines digging straight through the hardened leather
> and into his flesh. The folding blade of the Mantis’s claw was closed
> about Stenwold’s throat like a clasp-knife, and it was impossible for
> him to tell whether it had drawn blood or not.
>
> —Tchaikovsky, Adrian. *Empire in Black and Gold (Shadows of the Apt Book 1* (p. 267))

Initially I assumed this was the palm of one hand, and the forearm of the other. But the next line is something like "In his other hand Tisamon..." So he clearly did that one-handed.

I have picked up, but not fully understood that mantis kinden have unique physiology and/or armour (I'm not clear which), and that real praying mantises have limbs that would allow that.

[image: photo of a praying mantis. The upper limb is clearly able to fold in on itself.]

Also that Tisamon has folding blades, but those aren't mentioned? I've also seen some official and unofficial art, but that's hasn't helped me.

So how does he catch her blade?

Comment: Probable quotation added.

Comment: It sounds like Mantis anatomy has forearm spines that can be used in opposition to the palm of the hand, but we'd need images to be sure.  They'd have to also fold flat to avoid self-injury.